# How to copy xcode ui files from one project to another?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am new to xcode and swift. I downloaded a simple login application from the internet, developed the application to a larger application by adding 10 UIs and swift codes. Due to signing/licening problems in the downloaded login app, I need to start a completely new project. Is it possible to grab the ui files from the previous project to the latest project.

Comment: Just drag and drop. Make sure you check the copy files when dragging and dropping.

Comment: do you want to copy the complete XIB of or ViewController or just someViews from that.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The easiest way is to drag the files into the new Xcode project and check the check box "Copy files if needed".

But you could also solve the signing problems. This not some kind of magic. It's just a collection of files.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Its so simple just click the storyboard and open it as source code .

1.Then copy the xml fully

3.then paste the xml in to your new project storyboard source code .

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy Views from one project to another then just select your view from Document Outline and copy by pressing command + C and go to the project where you want to paste the view ,open document outline and paste by pressing command +V.